# TimeSeriesForecast and BusinessDay

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

Question: I want to do a timeforecast for the next 30 days, but only the business days (weekends excluded). My dataset look likes:

```
data={{DateObject[{2020, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}], 541.92},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0.}], 560.01},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 17, 0, 0, 0.}], 566.48},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0.}], 562.61},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 19, 0, 0, 0.}], 567.83},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 565.07},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 23, 0, 0, 0.}], 574.19},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0.}], 557.33}, 
{DateObject[{2020, 6, 25, 0, 0, 0.}], 560.41},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 26, 0, 0, 0.}], 559.82},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 29, 0, 0, 0.}], 560.16},{DateObject[{2020, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0.}], 559.73},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}], 562.67}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0.}], 570.75},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0.}], 568.63}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0.}], 578.52},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0.}], 575.52},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0.}], 572.18},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0.}], 567.38},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0.}], 570.52},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 13, 0, 0, 0.}], 578.85},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 14, 0, 0, 0.}], 572.51},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0.}], 577.56},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 16, 0, 0, 0.}], 573.94},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 17, 0, 0, 0.}], 573.8},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 20, 0, 0, 0.}], 579.14},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 21, 0, 0, 0.}], 581.29},{DateObject[{2020, 7, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 572.9}, 
{DateObject[{2020, 7, 23, 0, 0, 0.}], 576.67}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 24, 0, 0, 0.}], 563.95}}

dataFit = 
 TimeSeriesModelFit[TimeSeries[TimeSeriesResample[data]], "ARIMA", 
  Method -> Automatic]
```

without 'TimeSeriesResample'it doesn't work.

When I want te forecast the next 30 days like

```
dataFC = TimeSeriesForecast[dataFit, {30}]
```

the result is a dataset and weekends are included.

Is there a method available that you can do forecast for only businessdays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is no change expected over the weekends or holidays:

```
dataFC = Table[{
  DatePlus[Last[data][[1]], {n, "BusinessDay"}], 
  TimeSeriesForecast[dataFit, n]
}, {n, 1, 30}];
```